# How to install Truecrypt?

Tags: truecrypt

I have recently downloaded truecrypt from www.truecrypt.org and got a .tar.gz file. I am completely new to ubuntu and dont know how to install it.Please help and give extra details.

Comment: For a more in depth look at installing and running truecrypt, see  http://askubuntu.com/questions/166199/

Answer (score 3):

Truecrypt comes with a compressed installer script. Just extract the .tar.gz file and go to the folder and click on the "truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x86" file. It will ask you for your administrator password and after entering it it will install truecrypt.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 12.04, you might also take a look at the solution in this answer:

- [How to install truecrypt via apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174872/i-cant-install-truecrypt-on-ubuntu-12-04/230951#230951) (question: I can't install Truecrypt on Ubuntu 12.04)

It is no official repository, but at least it allows you to use the apt-get package