# How do I encrypt files after skipping the option during installation?

Tags: files, encryption

I need to encrypt some files on my machine. I did not select the option do encrypt my home folder at installation, but since there was an option to do so I am guessing that Ubuntu has some inbuilt encryption utility. If so, what is it and can I use it to encrypt certain files on my system (not just home folder) ??

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/366749/enable-disk-encryption-after-installation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the following two encryption programs: `truecrypt` and `openssl`; the first allows you to create any size of encrypted container, and the second allows you to encrypt individual files; folders must be tarred before encrypting, as the target to be encrypted must be one single chunk of data.

- `Truecrypt` is an excellent program, but is not available in the repositories, so you must go to [truecrypt.org](http://www.truecrypt.org/downloads) to download the program; you want the 'standard' version, and it is available in 32 or 64bit. After downloading, open the terminal and cd to the containing folder and enter `tar -zxvf <truecrypt download file>`, and then `chmod +x <truecrypt setup file>`, and then `sudo ./<truecrypt setup file>`.  (You need to use sudo as it will install to the system folders.)
- Then follow the onscreen prompts and `truecrypt` will be installed. After that it is best to run it as `normal user` when you want to create a volume, but with `gksudo` when you want to mount a volume. (If you create a volume as `gksudo`, root will own it, and so you would have to chown it for your user to regain ownership.)
- When creating a volume in `truecrypt`, there are a lot of options, and even whole usb flash drives, external hard drives, internal hard disk partitions, and more can be encrypted. Even though a long discussion of these aspects of the program is not relevant to this answer, there are several other important things to note. In particular, it can be useful to format the `truecrypt` volume's filesystem in FAT32. The volume will then be easy to open if the file is transferred to a Windows system, as a volume created with the FAT32 option will be able to be opened by the Windows `truecrypt` executable.
- The volume `truecrypt` creates is in a sense similar to that created with virtualbox; i.e. a virtual disk with its own filesystem. There is good documentation on the site that explains in great detail how to use the program. Also, after installation the pdf guide should be in `/usr/share/truecrypt/doc/TrueCrypt User Guide.pdf`.
- I also use `openssl` (installed as default) to encrypt various files and tarred archives. I use the same commands as given in this section of the [Unix toolbox](http://cb.vu/unixtoolbox.xhtml#crypt), but I repeat them here for completeness, credit to Colin Barschel. The first command `encrypts`; the second `decrypts` in both the files and the folder examples:

  ***For files:***

  Encrypt:

  ```
  openssl aes-128-cbc -salt -in file -out file.aes
  ```

  Decrypt:

  ```
  openssl aes-128-cbc -d -salt -in file.aes -out file
  ```

  ***For tarred folders:***

  Encrypt:

  ```
  tar -cf - directory | openssl aes-128-cbc -salt -out directory.tar.aes
  ```

  Decrypt:

  ```
  openssl aes-128-cbc -d -salt -in directory.tar.aes | tar -x -f -
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Here you are. There is a how-to on the community help Wiki:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostInstallationEncryption

Answer (score 2):

Try [Cryptkeeper](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/encrypt-protect-computer-files-cryptkeeper-linux/). You can use this to encrypt specific folders.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) instead because it gives you more control over encryption and offers you more options.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new Gnome EncFS Mountmanager

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/gnome-encfs-manager-cryptkeeper.html

Crytkeeper is at the end of its lifetime. I will not be developed any more. It is not working in 12.10++.

I installed the Gnome EncFS Mountmanager in Ubuntu 13.10 without any problems.

Greets
Axel