# Ubuntu - encrypted root, logistics

Tags: luks, initramfs, cryptsetup

I am attempting to boot Ubuntu on a LUKS encrypted device - In a prior life, I specified the UUID as a kernel cmdline option and then the initramfs opened up that device with the credentials I provided.

From all the documentation I am seeing, it appears to me that I must build the initramfs with the device I want to unlock beforehand.

So, let's say I have 3 USB devices that I want to boot to.  Instead of keeping all of the contents identical and tweaking the kernel cmdline, I would keep everything the same, BUT change the initramfs for each one to reference the device properly?  The problem with that for me is that how do I easily generate the initramfs when my root FS is a squashfs image?

References:

[How do I automatically decrypt an encrypted filesystem on the next reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996155/how-do-i-automatically-decrypt-an-encrypted-filesystem-on-the-next-reboot)

https://www.pavelkogan.com/2014/05/23/luks-full-disk-encryption/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried updating the initramfs again and this initramfs worked.  I didn't change my kernel cmdline, so I am guessing that either the build process (I was using) didn't invoke update initramfs OR I didn't copy the latest file.

My kernel cmdline is still:

```
linux /vmlinuz-5.0.0-34-generic consoleblank=300 root=<DEVICE> rootfstype=squashfs rw cryptopts=source=/dev/disk/by-uuid/<UUID>,lvm,rootdev overlayroot=tmpfs:recurse=0
```