# Automatically unlock LUKS encrypted disk on boot

Tags: boot, server, luks

Im new to (command line) linux, and as a learning exercise i decided to turn my old PC i had lying arround into a linux server running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. However, while i was configuring it, i like a complete dummy chose to encrypt entire hard drive.

That is not a good thing for me, since i want my "server" to automatically start some thing i have on it if it for some reason reboots without me having to do anything about it. So naturally, first thing i tried was seeing if there was a way to remove the encryption on my disk, but that requires a copying all my data to another hard drive, wich i dont have.

Then i saw on a VERY OLD answer to a question here that it might be possible to have your password stored in plain text on a non encrypted part of the disk, and have it be automatically inputed for you, but with no mention of how.

Sooo how would i go about doing that? (Btw i understand that it renders the encryption useless, but i dont really care, its not needed for my purposes). Also please explain what everything does on your answer if possible, the whole point of this was to learn anyways

Comment: If you have no place to back up, you have a much bigger problem... The best path is to reinstall the OS without the encryption

Comment: I was afraid of this, the setup for it isint exactly very pratical, since i have to configure the wifi again wich was pretty annoying but i guess its the only way. Thanks

Comment: You can do it, but you have to be very very careful with it.  I tried it once, missed 1 step and rendered my OS useless.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/996155/how-do-i-automatically-decrypt-an-encrypted-filesystem-on-the-next-reboot

Comment: You said this was a learning experience and you figured it out the first time so it shouldn't be difficult this time.

Comment: yeah, i know what im doing this time arorund, i was just hopping to avoid redoing my last 3 days or so but its defitively doable, in fact im lucky i found this very early on, otherwise i would have to reinstall way more than what i have to now. Thanks for the help. (do i have to mark this as closed or something now?)