# Is it possible to auto-unlock my Bitlocker-encrypted storage drive on Ubuntu 21.04/21.10?

Tags: boot, password, encryption

I have a storage drive encrypted with Bitlocker and I can currently access it on Ubuntu 21.04 through Nautilus by manually typing in the password. I have read that it is [possible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996155/how-do-i-automatically-decrypt-an-encrypted-filesystem-on-the-next-reboot) to automatically unlock a LUKS-encrypted drive on logon but I was wondering if this is also possible on a Bitlocker-encrypted drive with `cryptsetup`. I have read some [solutions](https://superuser.com/questions/1598661/how-can-i-unlock-a-bitlocker-encrypted-volume-using-linux) which use `dislocker` but are there any alternatives?