# What is truecrypt?

Tags: software-recommendation, truecrypt

I hear people in Ask Ubuntu talk about software called **true crypt**. I know it is used to for encryption but I do not know more.

1. How does it encrypt data?
2. Is it available for Ubuntu
3. How can I use it?

Comment: Also, see the answers for [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/166199/how-do-i-encrypt-files-after-skipping-the-option-during-installation), as they should be useful regarding `truecrypt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TrueCrypt creates TrueCrypt volume containers (encrypted files) where you store your secret data. Later you can mount it like any other volume, by providing the password/keyfile. The good thing is that it works "on the fly", in other words, it encrypts/decrypts the data in RAM before making changes to disk, as you write/read files to/from the volume. It can also encrypt full partitions/drives. For the documentation, see: http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/

Answer (score 0):

As you said it is a software for encryption, for more information you'd better have a look at http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/.